# Simple Syntax for Declaring properties with a starting value

Tags: c#, properties, syntactic-sugar

Well so far, the shortest code I've seen to declare a property that can be set only from inside the class I've seen is:

```
public T Property {get; private set;}
```

But what if I want to declare it already with a starting value (which is not the default value for that type), how could I do it??

Actually I'm doing this:

```
public T Property {get; private set;}
private void Initialize() {Property = Value; }
```

Another option is:

```
private T _Property = Value;
public property {get {return _Property;}}
```

But I'm wondering if I can write that with ONE code line only, because I'll be writing many of those properties, and I don't want to have a duplicate line for each.

Comment: how about using the class ctor to initialize the prop values?

Comment: Would be the same, two lines per property. That would cause coding errors when class grows big.

Comment: Constructor calls Initialize. I've separated it because of many constructor overloads requiring a particular sequence.

Comment: Are the properties values unique or are you just looking to change the default value of the type?

Comment: Unique. In fact I would like them to be constants, but they're classes and delegates, cannot declare them constants.

Comment: If there's a way to change default values of a type, I'd like to know, just by curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.  Auto-properties *always* default to their default value.

Your best bet is to set them in the constructor, or else just not use an auto-property.

```
public T Property {get; private set;}
public MyClass() {
   Property = Value; 
}
```